# MSBuild copy dlls to bin folder, not following the path

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I am using csproj file to bundle Chrome windows edition into our ASP.NET Core app. I place all the needed files into `$(ProjectDir)\chrome-win` and use below XML to copy the files in `csproj`

```
<None Update="chrome-win\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" LinkBase="chrome-win\" />
```

What is strange is that when I publish the project using the built in folder publish profile, all the `*.dll` files gets copied to `bin\chrome-win\` and other files are in `chrome-win\`. This is so frustrating, how can I tell stupid MSBuild / Visual Studio to not to do this? When I build it, the behavior is even stranger, the `*.dll` files gets copied twice, once to `chrome-win` folder, also gets copied to `bin` folder.

I am using the latest VS 2019 and MSBuild

Comment: I'm not aware of a standard way to do this, if you have files in a subfolder with copy to output set, they'll get copied including the subfolder. An alternative solution would be to add a build-event to copy the content of the folder to the output directory. You can use some macros for both source and output directory so you can use relative paths.

Comment: @Steeeve the problem with build event is that it's not cross platform, also might not work with publishing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to use the [$(BaseOutputPath)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/common-msbuild-project-properties?view=vs-2019&redirectedfrom=MSDN&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2015) property for your copy so that everything writes into the same folder. So it would look like this.

```
<None Update="chrome-win\**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Always" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" LinkBase="$(BaseOutputPath)\chrome-win\" />
```

EDIT1:

If you want all the contents of the bin folder moved to `\bin\chrome-win\` you could use the [CopyTask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/copy-task?view=vs-2019)

```
<Copy SourceFiles="$(BaseOutputPath)\*" DestinationFiles="$(BaseOutputPath)\" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" />
```

You might need to tweak this a bit but it should do what you need.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it seems doesn't work, all the `*.dll` files are copied to bin folder and other files stayed in `chrome-win`

Comment: Oh if you just want to have it all flat in the bin folder just remove the `\chrome-win` in the `LinkBase` attribute

Comment: no, I want all the `*.dll` files in `chrome-win` folder, not in `bin` folder as it's necessary for the dlls don't change path so the bundling works

Comment: hi Max, my problem is this, I expect all files of `chrome-win` folder to stay in `chrome-win` folder after publishing . But the actual outcome is that Visual Studio treat `*.dll` specially and moved all `*.dll` files to `bin` folder, but other non dll files stayed in `chrome-win` folder. This is quite strange, and not what I wanted.

Comment: @imgen Tested on my side, but I didn't use Chrome Windows edition and other things, just create some test files in `chrome-win` folder, and addedd the same MSBuild code line. But the result was MSBuild copied **all** the files to the `chrome-win` folder. This issue is weird. I am not sure if it is because I didn't use Chrome Windows edition or other things, but do you install some extensions, use some other MSBuild code lines, add some build events? Set the `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Detailed` will be helpful to check which task moved the `*.dll` files in Output window.

Comment: @Tianyu great. Thanks for testing! I think the problem you see is that you only build it, didn't publish it. When build it, actually, the `*.dll` files gets copied to `chrome-win` and `bin` folder which is also not what I wanted behavior, but at least `chrome-win` folder is intact. But when publish it, the `*.dll` only gets copied to bin folder. You can use a folder publish profile to verify this behavior. I think this might be a bug of `MSBuild`. Will update my question to make it very clear.

Comment: @MaxYoung I will test it out. BTW, my problem is not with building, it's with publishing to a folder using the built-in folder publish profile

Comment: @MaxYoung I updated my question to make my issue a bit clearer

Comment: @MaxYoung tried the `Copy` task, doesn't work as it doesn't support a folder as source files.

Comment: @imgen What about trying to use [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-items?view=vs-2019#use-wildcards-to-specify-items) with the CopyTask which Max mentioned to specify files in the folder?

Comment: @Tianyu tried that as well, not working. Maybe it's because my project type is Azure Functions, maybe other types of project will work. Anyway, I gave up on this. I think MSBuild is quite bad for publishing / deploying. Done with stupid XML.